# Getting a 500 error when using an ajax get call

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I am getting a 500 Internal Server Error when trying to use an Ajax .get call.  I double checked that the method name is the same in the get call as it is in the Route above the method.  Not sure why I am getting the 500 error and how to fix it.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('#New_Note').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this);
        url = $form.attr("action");

        term = $form.find("input[name='Note']").val();
        console.log(url);

        var posting = $.post( url, { Note: term } );

        var get = $.get("getLastEntry");//This line causes the 500 error                 
    });
```

Here is my method in my .cs file

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("getLastEntry")]
public IActionResult GetLastEntry()
{
        ViewBag.Notes = userFactory.GetLast();
        return View();
}
```

Here is the `GetLast` method

```
public IEnumerable<Home> GetLast()
{
            using (IDbConnection dbConnection = Connection)
            {
                dbConnection.Open();
                return dbConnection.Query<Home>("SELECT * FROM notes ORDER BY Id LIMIT 1");
            }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you debug it?

Comment: @Liam how do I debug a server error?

Comment: Recreate it locally? We can't re-create it with this information. So your best placed to fix this

Comment: Can you check what URL it is forming when you send AJAX request?
I doubt it will form correct URL with $.get("getLastEntry")

Comment: apply breakpoint and then debug. Use F9 key to add breakpoint in VS.

Comment: @yogihosting, would love too, but am using visual studio code on a mac

Answer (score 1):

Can you try following?

```
  $('button').click(function(){
                   $('#New_Note').submit(function(event){
                       event.preventDefault();
                      var $form = $( this );
                      url = $form.attr( "action" );

                      term = $form.find( "input[name='Note']" ).val();
                      console.log(url);
                      var posting = $.post( url, { Note: term } );

                      var get = $.get("@Url.RouteUrl("getLastEntry")");//Change here                 
                    });

});
```

Comment: I am getting an expected ',' error.  I changed the middle quotes to ticks and got too many characters in character literal

Comment: No need to change quotes, just make sure you have closed all parentheses properly

Answer (score 1):

500 error says that you routing is OK. You have to read error message which the server responds. You can find it in browser (developer tools usually called by F12 hotkey). Also you must have such item `<customErrors mode="Off" />` in Web.config.

Error may be in anything: connection string, strange syntax `using (IDbConnection dbConnection = Connection)` or in .cshtml file.

Comment: i first tried $.get("routeName") and i too got 500 on my machine. It generated "https://localhost:9457/Web/MyAction/routeName" and treated "routeName" as id parameter. It depends how your routes are defined.

Comment: you right, but anyway we need just to know error message to give right answer

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `GET` to make ajax calls. I've seen situations where a bad requests gets cached, and continues to be served despite the code being fine. Switching the protocol to `POST` will either validate or invalidate my answer for you.